# Automated Textual feedback analysis in Java/Python

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, nlp

I need to develop an automated learning based Textual Feedback analysis system for a set of online courses, pretty much like the usual MOOCs such as Coursera, EdX, etc. What Java/Python tools/services can be used. The system should scan the sentence understand it's implication. For eg.

**Input:** "This course is very informative."

**Output**: **Set** positive-feedback for course observed flag.

**Input**: "The instructor's language skills were poor."

**Output**: **Set** positive-feedback for instructor observed flag..

**Input**: "The course material was not adequate."

**Output**: **Set** negative-feedback for course observed flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very general. Here are some link to start with.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml does sentiment scoring out of the box using Socher et al's sentiment model.

Python's NLTK is also a good place to start. Here is a blog post on how to use it to build a sentiment analyizer:
http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/

Also TextBlob (also python) has a pretrained sentiment classifier:
http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @J Thanks for the help. :) 
Can Lesk's Algorithm be used for such Sentiment Analysis

Comment: Potentially word sense disambiguation could be useful. There is a leak implementation in nltk. Www.nltk.org/howto/wsd.html